# #1052 - Column 'noMyKid' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: sql, database, mysql-error-1052

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),tarikhmohon) AS hari
FROM mohon a 
INNER JOIN tblstatus_tak_lengkap b on a.noMyKid=b.nomykid 
WHERE noMyKid=130902100437
```

I have tried that SQL but I got an error.

> #1052 - Column 'noMyKid' in where clause is ambiguous.

I can't find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column `noMyKid` is present is both tables. You should tell the server on what table the column you want to filter, eg

```
WHERE a.noMyKid = 130902100437
```

or

```
WHERE b.noMyKid = 130902100437
```

Whatever you use, it doesn't matter since you are using `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the column "noMyKid" in both tables.

Prefix it like this : a.noMyKid

Answer (score 0):

try changing to

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),tarikhmohon) AS hari
FROM mohon a 
INNER JOIN tblstatus_tak_lengkap b on a.noMyKid=b.nomykid 
WHERE a.noMyKid=130902100437
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `mohon` and `tblstatus_tak_lengkap` both have a `noMyKid` column (at least on installs with case-insensitive column names). In your `WHERE` clause, you need to specify which table you want to be reading the `noMyKid` from.

As you're joining on the value already, which table you pick doesn't matter, so something like this will work fine:

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),tarikhmohon) AS hari
FROM mohon a 
INNER JOIN tblstatus_tak_lengkap b on a.noMyKid=b.nomykid 
WHERE a.noMyKid=130902100437
```